# load wxWidget pdb library in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, wxwidgets

I am confused here, I want to download wxWidget binaries that I can use in microsoft visual studio, the file is tar.gz, I think the file I downloaded contains * .lib, *. Dll files, and header files, but it contains Pdb file, then how do i use wxWidget Library which is PDB?

Sorry, i just beginner using visual c++, i'm usually using codeblock and gcc

Comment: I suggest to compile the library yourself. Then in case you need to confirm something you can compile the sample and check. Download the sources or clone the git tree and compile.

Comment: I also think so, OK I will try it, maybe with download binaries, I can work faster, I successfully compile with Mingw, but I have difficulties with Visual c ++, I open the file solution in visual studio but failed to build, iam using vs 2015, any suggestions? Can binaries from Mingw be used in visual c ++?

Answer (score 0):

I Successfully compile it
I have downloaded the latest source, i open the wx_vc14.sln file, i can compile it with visual studio 2015, easily, sorry i downloaded the old source, my friend can compile it easily with visual studio 2010,

Thanks